# .htaccess direct users to new folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

Could somebody please help me out with an issue I have. I currently have upgraded my site. I would like old folder name and anything that comes after it, to link to direct to the root of my new folder name

www.example.com/oldFolder/

www.example.com/newFolder/

Normally i could write this in .htaccess with no problems, but there's a twist which is beyond my knowledge level. I need `www.example.com/oldFolder/` and ANYTHING that comes after it to be directed to `www.example.com/newFolder/` (at the root of newfolder).

I was thinking something like this, but need further advice

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^www.example.com/oldFolder/* www.example.com/newFolder/ [R=301,L]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^www.example.com/oldFolder/(.*) www.example.com/newFolder/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks, @Karl, that's nearly fixed it. I just tested it, the only thing is it keeps the files AFTER the old folder and adds them to the end of the newfolder domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldFolder(/.*)$ /newFolder/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is also adding to the end of `newFolder/`

Comment: This is just redirecting to `http://site.com/newFolder/` is that not what you expect?

Comment: That's what I expect but it is also keeping the sub pages, which i would not like. eg at the moment your code does this: from `http://site.com/oldFolder/product.php?oldProdcut=123` to `http://site.com/newFolder/product.php?oldProdcut=123`. I would like `http://site.com/oldFolder/product.php?oldProdcut=123` to `http://site.com/newFolder/`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
 RewriteRule ^www.example.com/oldFolder/(.*) www.example.com/newFolder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will set the **moved permanently** header whenever someone wants to reach old url and it will keep params after `/`

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way of not adding anything onto the end of newFolder`? as i want it to go to the index.php page.

Comment: It cannot work since RewriteRule doesn't match hostname, it only matches REQUEST_URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify an actual page it shouldn't redirect and keep everything else intact. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^www.example.com/oldFolder/(.*)$ www.example.com/newFolder/index.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I tried that but it has the exact effect. It removes `index.php` and puts in it's place the url that would have followed `oldFolder`

Answer (score 0):

Word of advice. If your re-directing a huge portion of your traffic you are creating more work for the server doing this. Not so much that you need to worry but I'm just wondering if you have created the new folder out of making development easy i.e. having a live site while you work on a copy of it then switch over?